# Magento include phtml file within another phtml file

Tags: magento-1, phtml, cms, tags

I am making a custom home page for my magento website in a phtml file named home_banner.phtml, which in turn i have referenced in the CMS->Pages->Home Page content by the following code

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"}}
```

In my home_banner.phtml I have called tags/popular.phtml to display the popular tags.

```
<div class="last-posts-grid clearfix">

     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

</div>
```

However the tags are not being displayed even though the anchor tag which says "view all tags" id getting called correctly. The ul class="tags-list" is also visible in the page source but the tags themselves are not visible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need change  block type `core/template` to `tag/popular`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('tag/popular')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

OR

give a name of block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

then

by using xml reference include  tags/popular.phtml

create local.xml at app/design/frontend/youupackage/yourtemplate/layout

put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index translate="label">
      <reference name="myname">
            <block type="tag/popular" name="home_tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

and put below code at **home_banner.phtml**

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('home_tags_popular');
```

Comment: thanx amit....your 1st suggestion worked. Any idea where I can get the respective reference names of different magento elements. Like tags/popular is for displaying popular tags. What if I wanna include newsletter subscription forms, newest products, etc. What will I have to write instead of tag/popular then??? core/template does not work