# convert widget block codes to phtml and xml layout

Tags: layout, blocks, xml, phtml, widget

Sorry I am new to Magento and please bear with me if I am not using the proper terms. So I got an extension and it can be integrated anywhere on my CMS or any pages with the following codes:

```
{{block type="dailydeal/list_sidedeals" slim="true" name="dailydeal_sidedeals_block" template="dailydeal/list/featured_deal.phtml" }}
```

But for some reason I need to have this widget block written inside the relative phtml file instead of the backend so I found this earlier post:[Magento include phtml file within another phtml file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38008/magento-include-phtml-file-within-another-phtml-file)

So came up with the following for my phtml file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dailydeal/list_sidedeals')->setTemplate('dailydeal/list/featured_deal.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

It works only half way. Notice there is some additional attributes(sorry if I did not name this correctly) in my first widget block such as `slim="true"` and `name="dailydeal_sidedeals_block"`. Are they something I need to add into my relative xml layout file? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass value to block by `setSlim`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('dailydeal/list_sidedeals')->setSlim(true)->setTemplate('dailydeal/list/featured_deal.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```